# How can I tell if I have static or dynamic IP Address?

Tags: fedora-13, static-ip, dynamic-ip

Maybe a stupid question but how can I tell if I have a static IP address or a dynamic IP address?
Running Fedora-13

Comment: thanks for the answers, guys. I'll try some of these out tonight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asking the ISP or network administrator or physically checking the settings is the easiest way because:

If you are talking about the address provided by your ISP, then switching your router off for a while will eventually force the ISP to release your old IP. Unfortunately, you could be unlucky and your "new" IP may be exactly the same as your old one. This means that switching off your router for a while is not a 100% foolproof way of finding out if your IP is static or dynamic. It usually works, though.

If you are talking about your LAN IP then check your router and see if it is selected to provide an IP from a static table or through DHCP, if it's DHCP then you may still end up with the same IP depending on how long the router remembers an IP address allocation before releasing it. Most domestic routers seem to keep them forever, despite the settings.

Answer (score 1):

For public IP addresses, some sites such as [WhatIsMyIPAddress.com](http://whatismyipaddress.com/)<sup>†</sup> claim their databases can tell if your IP address is static or dynamic.

Also, sometimes running a `dig -x your-ip-address` might reveal a DNS name that includes some hints from your provider, like `dyn` prefixes. It's all not standardized though, so indeed the best bet is to get that information from your provider.

<sup><sup>†</sup> In my case the answer is correct; see the "Additional IP Details" button.</sup>

Comment: here is my output, do you see any clues?                            ; <<>> DiG 9.7.1-P2-RedHat-9.7.1-2.P2.fc13 <<>> -x 66.30.118.173
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9999
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;173.118.30.66.in-addr.arpa. IN PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
173.118.30.66.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN PTR c-66-30-118-173.hsd1.ma.comcast.net.

;; Query time: 47 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Nov 29 19:56:54 2010
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 93

Comment: @Ramy, the part `c-x-x-x-x.hsd1.ma.comcast.net` is the DNS name that your provider has assigned. Apart from *maybe* C=Cable, HSD=High Speed Data and MA=Massachusetts, no clues there (though Comcast wants it [for 3rd party email](http://customer.comcast.com/Pages/FAQViewer.aspx?seoid=ES000010)). Using "Additional IP Details" for your IP address gets you to http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip which claims: ISP: Comcast Cable, Type: Broadband, Assignment: Dynamic IP`. Not 100% accurate, but I guess it's true: their website only seems to mention static IP addresses for business tier subscriptions.

Comment: for my dynamic IP (changes every 2-3 days), whatismyipaddress.com says "static", so it's definitely not always accurate. but I think that their guess for Comcast is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to find out would be to call your ISP if you're asking about a home connection, and to call your sysadmin if you're on a work or school campus.

It's fairly rare these days to find connections that come with static IP addresses; usually if you want one you have to pay extra for it.

Other way to find out is to login to your gateway device (your modem or router) and check the settings; it will show you if you have a static or dynamically-assigned IP address.